# How to turn the user agent into a secure_user_agent?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, user-agent

I am using FireFox 34.0.5 and trying to change my user agent.

As far as I am aware, an user agent is, somehow, a software acting on your behalf. For example, I am using FireFox now, hence my user agent is FireFox.

I have download two add-ons in order to try to change it. They are 'User Agent Switcher' and 'Tamper Data' but it did not work, whatsoever. The reason that it did not work is because I need a "secure_user_agent" in fact I have been told that I ought to merely change the user agent in "about:config" and change it to a **secure** one.

I really cannot get it.

My default user agent is - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0

How can I turn it into a **secure** User Agent?

The truth is that I have to start up a FireFox page with a secure user agent because the default one is not accepted, not allowed. I have been told that I should look for something secure in the source code ....but I have not got it yet.

I have got Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95, as well, if that can make things easier.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: How do you know it "did not work?" There is no such thing as `secure_user_agent` in the HTTP standard.

Comment: They mean to change it to literally be the word secure_user_agent http://completelyunoptimized.com/2014/06/20/hackthis-basic-level-1-5/

Answer (score 1):

open the Developer Tools ( Ctrl + shift + i ) 
click the device icon at the left top of the  Developer Tools window ( beside the search icon )
a device mode will appear in the top of your web page 
in front of UA (User Agent) replace the "no override" with "secure_user_agent"

Comment: Can you clarify your answer? It's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Here is a link that explains what you should do step by step : https://winaero.com/blog/change-user-agent-firefox/

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND THE ANSWER!!!!!

1. Ctrl+Shift+I
2. Click on the menu button next to "x" button
3. Click show console drawer (if its already shown just leave it like that)
4. Click the console drawer menu button (next to console tab)
5. Select "Network conditions"
6. Click the "Network conditions" tab
7. Scroll down to user agent and uncheck select automatically
8. In the enter a custom agent type "secure_user_agent" (secure_user_agent was what i was need to put in there)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, user agent is: "What my web browser identifies itself as to websites"

So, when you go to google chrome store, it asks the browser "what is the user agent", and based on the reply it might tell you "this browser is not compatible" or "you appear to be using internet explorer, we suggest you install chrome" or "you have the latest version of google chrome" and let you install apps.

The only time you want to ever change your user agent, is if for some reason you need to lie to a website about what browser you are using. For example, if you have a custom build of chromium and you want to download apps from the google chrome webstore, it won't let you unless you put in the useragent for the latest version of good chrome.

This has nothing to do with security.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+Shift+I
2. Click on the menu button next to "x" button
3. click show console drawer
4. Go to user agent and uncheck select automatically
5. In the enter a custom agent type "secure_user_agent"

Comment: Alright. This question was posted over 3 years ago, and is actually just asking how to send a web request with a spoofed user agent. It's a challenge from [HackThis!](https://alexandervoidstar.wordpress.com/2015/07/26/hackthis-basic-level-2-2/), and your answer will most likely be outdated by the next major release of Firefox. This challenge can be completed by intercepting a web request in a tool like BurpSuite and changing the User-Agent header to `secure_web_agent` before sending it to the target. Regardless, I'm sorry to say that your answer will likely never help anyone. You tried though.

Comment: I have just tried it and it is still working in chrome 71

Comment: the Network Conditions tab is not visible by default. The fact that this is a 4 year old question still stands though.